# Automatic log-out if no activity found on page with dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Heres my working script which i've also found in this site and after idle time expire, alert message will pop up and it will direct to specific page.

However what I would like to do instead is after idle time expire it will call a dialog box where user can choose "Keep sign in" or "Exit" buttons.. How can set-up dialog box with javascipt and call it? Sorry I'm just a newbie. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 5; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onkeypress = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
    _idleSecondsCounter++;
    var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
    if (oPanel)
        oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";

    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        //alert("Time expired!");
        //document.location.href = "logout.html";

        CALL_A_DIALOG_BOX()



    }
}
```

Comment: The title is a little misleading. But for your question, you should look into the `confirm` method for JS ( example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) ) or into `dialog` for jquery ( example [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) )

Comment: sorry for my question.. the second example is really great, but how can i download all the code including the js and css?. thank you.

Comment: To use `jquery` and `dialog` you need to include both the `jquery` and the `jquery ui` libraries. You can find the first at [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/), and the second at [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/). You can also use CDN libraries from [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). If you decide to go with this solution, also take a look at the [getting started page](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/)

Comment: i tried your solution and it works.. but now my problem is how i gonna call the dialog box if the idle time expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery then, Please use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: there's a way without jquery as well: [`confirm`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: But in this he can not change button text to "Keep sign in" and "Exit"

Comment: Ya there are other ways also to create JS confirm Dialog, but in my opinion if he can include jQuery in his page then this is the easiest way.

Comment: He can set a custom message like "You will be logged out" and will habe the "Ok" and "Exit" buttons

Comment: I totally agree that if you can use jquery, you should use modal confirmation from `dialog`, I was just adding the info specifically because of your `if you can` in the question (adding options)

Comment: thanks.. One more thing how can i get all the codes including the css and javascript?.

Comment: There is a view source link on the page where you can see the whole code. Including js and css links

Comment: but only the link to js and css.. no source code for the css and js.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: one more thing how i gonna call the dialog box if idle time expire?

Comment: $( ".selector" ).dialog( "open" );